# Integrate webpack template with Django

Tags: django, django-templates, static

I'm working on a Django project, and I'm trying to integrate an HTML template built with npm using webpack into the Django project.
I'm curious about the necessity of these {% static %} tags in the HTML templates.

**Issue:**

When visiting a URL like **/view/user**, static files are being loaded from **/view/user** instead of the expected **/static**. This happens because I am not adding the {% static %} template tag in the html templates.

**Question:**

Is there is a Django setting in order to avoid adding the `{% static %}` template tag to each line and save time? Has anyone encountered this problem before?

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'events_core/frontend/dist')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'events_core/frontend/dist'),
]
```